# Motion Chart - Font Type

Tags: font-face, google-visualization

I know that I can't change the font type/face in Google Motion Chart.

Can anyone tell me what font face/type motion chart is using?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out closest font by using [Identifont](http://www.identifont.com/). It is Arial 12pt.

In case, if people looking for the same thing like me.